# планирую отслужить там(,) сколько нужно(,) потише да побыстрее

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

> Лично я планирую отслужить там(,) сколько нужно(,) потише да побыстрее, а потом сесть на первый же корабль в любое тёплое место.

Нужны ли запятые в отмеченных местах?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оборот ***сколько нужно*** можно не обособлять (цельное по смыслу выражение), например: *Лично я планирую отслужить там **сколько нУжно,** а потом сесть на первый же корабль.* http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=146#pp146

Но в заданном предложении один из оборотов желательно обособить (в одну фразу они не читаются).

Можно предложить два варианта, расстановка логических ударений разная:

(1) *Лично я планирую отслужИть там **сколько нужно**, **потише да побыстрее**, а потом сесть на первый же корабль ― и в любое тёплое место*.

(2) *Лично я планирую отслужить там, **сколько нужно, потише да побыстрЕе,** а потом сесть на первый же корабль ― и в любое тёплое место.*

Пример: Насчет муки ― не стесняйся, бери сколько нужно.  [В. Л. Янин. Я послал тебе бересту… (1975)]

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Настоящей причиной обособления является сочетание двух обстоятельственных оборотов, которые не читаются в одну фразу. Поэтому один из оборотов включается в основное предложения, а другой обособляется. **Обособленный оборот при этом получает значение добавочного сообщения.**

При этом совершенно **неважна его грамматическая структура** (устойчивый оборот, или однородные обстоятельства, связанные союзом И, или что-то другое).

Comment: Во втором варианте ударение на "планирую", а дальше идёт уточнение. А у вас "сколько нужно" каким-то вводным получилось.

Comment: 1) Я говорю о фразовом логическом  ударении, а Вы о каком?    2) Вы любой обособленный оборот готовы назвать вводным? Для обособления существуют разные причины, например оборот может обособляться как содержащий дополнительную информацию.

Comment: Тоже о фразовом. Ударение должно куда-то упасть перед запятой. Иначе оно не читается.

Comment: С чего бы это? Там вставочная интонация, выделяется понижением тона внутри данной фразы, а ударение падает на конец фразы. И еще: хотелось бы увидеть ВАШ ОТВЕТ, а не только указание частных  (и не очень существенных) деталей в моем ответе

Comment: Так оно вообще не звучит. Тогда "сколько нужно" допустимо взять в скобки. Но это центральный элемент смысла, который не следует обособлять. || Так согласен с вашим ответом, кроме логического ударения, которое играет существенную роль в понимании смысла.

Comment: Полагаю, что автору вопроса всё это неинтересно (мелочи какие-то, под микроскопом их только рассматривать).  Неправильный ответ? Укажите грамматические и стилистические ошибки. И свой ответ приведите и обоснуйте. Согласны с постановкой знаков? Приведите только свое  обоснование.

Comment: Да нормально всё. Не воспринимайте всё так резко. Критика — путь у прогрессу.

Comment: Мелочная у Вас какая-то критика,  несерьезная, масштабности  ей не хватает.

Comment: У вас знания довольно приличные, чтобы допустить то, за что можно критиковать масштабно)